# How do I make numbered paragraphs (HTML5/CSS3)

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a QuickBASIC 4.5 guide in HTML5, and I've been getting a bunch of it working, but I want to know how I can number (or stop text-wrapping) my lines of code. For now, my code looks like this:

```
1. PRINT "Hello World!"
2. INPUT "Who are you? ", myName$
3. PRINT "Hello, " + myName$
4-7. (Stuff)
8. PRINT "Did you know that " + STR$(num1%) + " + " + STR$(num2%) + " = " + STR(total%) + "?"
```

So you see how when you scroll over the code there, it gives a scroller? I want to have that, but also I need to know how to make the numbering automatic.. right now it's in my < p >'s.. look:

```
<p class="code">1. PRINT "Hello World!" <br />
2. INPUT "Who are you? ", myName$ <br />
(...)</p>
```

I want to be able to do something, maybe in the CSS section, that gives scrolling and preferably the numbers. If you can get either one solved, just tell me.. I also looked on CSS3 and saw that the text-wrap property isn't used on any of the major browsers (yet), so maybe I can't do that, but then again the scrolling would just help with that. :P

---

Just if anybody wants to know, here's the CSS code for the code class:

```
 .code {
    font-family: Courier;
    margin-left: 35px;
    margin-right: 35px;
    background: #F0EFE9;
    border-style: inset;
    border-width: 5px;
    resize: vertical;
    overflow: auto;
    cursor: context-menu;
    /*text-wrap: none;*/ /* This doesn't work.. */
```

Comment: The way your HTML is set up, it's not possible using just CSS, since each code block consists of one element (by the way, why would you mark up code using a `p` element?).

Comment: You can use ordered list. See this link http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_lists.asp .

Comment: @BoltClock Ah, oh well. Also, because it feels like the only thing.. well, I guess I could use the `code` element.

Comment: @Pbk1303 Okay, I'll look there.

Comment: You can have a look at this [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/9ed5uzqk/) too. It uses CSS counters and pseudo-elements for auto-generating line numbers. **Note:** The markup is not the same as yours.

Comment: To mark an answer accepted, click the checkmark next to the answer. You do not need to edit your question to indicate that you found the answer - marking an answer as accepted does that for you.

Comment: No, seriously, you do not need to edit your question. The answers are right there. Putting the answer in the question just adds unnecessary clutter.

Comment: Ohkay. :P I guess that's true. xD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

an `<ol>` element will work instead of a url. By default an `<ol>` shows the numbers of the list items as a pose to the `<ul>` element etc

```
<ol>
<li> PRINT "Hello World!" </li>
<li>INPUT "Who are you? ", myName</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: I would seriously question using an `ol` element to mark up code, however, unless you frame it as "a list of lines of code", which seems strange IMO.

Comment: Okay, I will definitely try that. :)

Comment: @BoltClock i dont think he is using it for code - more like a list of instructions, thus the word PRINT

Comment: It's a list of instructions, but that's just what QBASIC code looks like - it's still code.

Comment: Oh, no, I'm using it for code, it's just, like in Python, the `PRINT` function basically logs something to the console of the program. ie, `PRINT "Hello World!"` will `PRINT` - stick something.. - at the end of the console. :P

Comment: ah, ok then. Be wary then. as the 1. 2. 3 etc will still be represented as text, so if copy/pasted then the numbers will still be passed into the clipboard

Answer (score 12):

```
<p>Paragraph </p>
<p>Paragraph </p>
<p>Paragraph </p>
<p>Paragraph </p>
<p>Paragraph </p>
<p>Paragraph </p>

<style type="text/css">
body {
  counter-reset: section;      
}
p:before {
  counter-increment: section;        
  content: "" counter(section) ": "; 
}
</style>
```

Comment: You appear to have a history of posting answers that consist of a single code block and nothing else - absolutely no explanation whatsoever. These are not good answers. Please try to explain your code.

Comment: Sorry to say but it just a simple CSS, i don't think to explain it.

Comment: I like this answer - it's a great idea, and is easily extended to do sub-paragraphs.

Comment: Great answer. The code speaks for itself and I can always look up the parts if I don't understand them. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using ordered list .

See this link http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_lists.asp.

`<ol> 
<li><p>hello world </p></li>
</ol>`