# Numbering paragraph in HTML while ignoring some of them

Tags: html, css

I refer to the answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25423807/how-do-i-make-numbered-paragraphs-html5-css3/25424618) from Ankur Kumar regarding adding paragraph number to a HTML file.

Is it possible to adjust the css code so that I can assign some of the paragraph of not being numbered (i.e. skipping number for that particular paragraph)?

Thanks!

This is my CSS:

```
body {
  counter-reset: section;      
}
p:before {
  counter-increment: section;        
  content: "" counter(section) ". "; 
}
```

And I just use `<p>` to encapsulate my paragraphs.

Comment: Where is your HTML? What code have you tried?

Comment: @disinfor please see my question updated, thanks!

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and how are the paragraphs to ignore identified

Answer (score 0):

From the same answer, just modify to use the `not` pseudo-class

```css
body {
  counter-reset: section;
}

p:not(.ignore):before {
  counter-increment: section;
  content: "" counter(section) ": ";
}
```

```html
<p>Paragraph </p>
<p>Paragraph </p>
<p>Paragraph </p>
<p>Paragraph </p>
<p class="ignore">Paragraph </p>
<p>Paragraph </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done without making use of an additional class with a combination of both the [`:not`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) *and* the [`:nth-of-type()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) (or [`:nth-child()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)) pseudo-classes:

```css
body {
  counter-reset: section;
}

p:not(:nth-of-type(5)):before {
  counter-increment: section;
  content: "" counter(section) ": ";
}
```

```html
<p>Paragraph</p>
<p>Paragraph</p>
<p>Paragraph</p>
<p>Paragraph</p>
<p>Paragraph</p>
<p>Paragraph</p>
```