# Is there any way to get the number of the current targeted child with css?

Tags: css

```
<div>
 <p>paragraph</p>
 <p>paragraph</p>
 <p>paragraph</p>
</div>
```

I would like to know which child I'm targeting in css, so there I can do something like:

```
div p:nth-child(n)::before{
 content: n + ' ';
}
```

And the output would be

1 pagragraph

2 pagragraph

3 pagragraph

Comment: Have you read: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25424618/82548?

Comment: I have not, thanks!

Comment: Why not using <li> with <ol> tags, this can be more clean.

Comment: what do you mean by *current targeted child* ? once clicked, or targeted via url#id , something else ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use this in css:

```
:root {
  counter-reset: paragraph;
} 

p:after {
  content: counter(paragraph);
  counter-increment: paragraph;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
:root {
  counter-reset: count;
} 

p:before {
  content: counter(count) '-';
  counter-increment: count;
}
```

```html
<div>
 <p>paragraph</p>
 <p>paragraph</p>
 <p>paragraph</p>
</div>
```